# VCC filtering for magnetic sensor on flat cable

Tags: sensor, decoupling-capacitor, ground-plane, decoupling

I'm designing an application for this magnetic angular sensor: 
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/4/7/8/0/1/MA700.pdf 
Because this is precise and sensitive piece, I'm thinking if I should have additional VCC filtering. Any thoughts welcome!

This sensor IC will sit on a tiny PCB, which will be connected to main controller board with SPI flat cable.

Should I place capacitor on the main board just before the cable? 
Should I place capacitor on the tiny PCB? 
Should I have inductor in addition to capacitor? 
Should I not worry about it at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the capacitor as close to the device as possible on the small board.  You might want a series inductor (also on the small board before the capacitor).  Do not omit the 100nF capacitor shown in the datasheet, put that capacitor closest to the part and a larger capacitor a little further away from the sensor chip than the 100nF (1uF is probably a good choice if you are not sure).

All of this depends on the amount of conducted EMI on the power input wires.

If the power is really bad, put a higher voltage on the power input to the board (possibly 5V) and put a high PSRR LDO on the small board to generate the 3.3V power rail for the sensor chip.

Shielded cable and connectors are probably a better solution than an additional capacitor and inductor.

Answer (score 1):

> This sensor IC will sit on a tiny PCB, which will be connected to main
>   controller board with SPI flat cable.

Whenever possible, interleave low-amplitude analog signals on a flat-cable between GND's. Although it requires more space on the PCB to fit a larger connector, this provides a shielding for the signal, particularly useful if the cable has lengh restriction.

Comment: Doesn't this introduce ground loop?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd Small ground loops are acceptable, preferred even. For example the wide area of a ground plane; or multiple conductors within the same cable, as suggested here.